# debug with multiple processes

Tags: java, debugging

I need to debug a project which starts multiple processes at the very beginning, all in Java.

My problem is that debugging such a code is very annoying. Because every time I finish a debug session all other processes stuck in memory and killing all of them is very annoying (since they do not have a process name and they are all "java").

Is it possible to do all the killings automatically?
or any other solution?

Comment: What platform/IDE are you using?

Comment: Is it possible to run all the processes in one JVM? e.g. one main() to call them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`process.destroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) in order to kill a subprocess. You can create a shutdown hook for your application and add this call to it.

You will need to test if this works in a debugger, but nevertheless, it is good to have anyway because it ensures your application shuts down cleanly.

Here is an example:

```
// start a sub process
final Process childProcess = new ProcessBuilder("some command").start();


// add a shutdown hook which will be invoked when the JVM is shutting down
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        childProcess.destroy();
    }
});
```

Comment: tnx, but I am wondering if a shutdown hook calls when I stop a debug session?

Comment: Not in eclipse. See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016. You'll have to test it out on Netbeans.

Comment: Neither in Netbeans. just tested!